# Show the series uniform convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Suppose $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Show that the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(\frac{z}{z_0})^n}$ converges uniformly on every closed disk $|z| \leq R$, if $R<|z_0|$.

My attempt: Since $|z| < |z_0| \Rightarrow |\frac{z}{z_0}|<1$. Then I stuck at here. I try to apply Abel's theorem here but I don know how to apply. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Ratio test is sufficient here..

Comment: but ratio test cannot show a convergence is uniform right?

Comment: Do you know the definition of uniform convergence? If so, choose the $N(\epsilon)$ that goes with $\epsilon$ for the convergence of the series $\sum (R/|z_0|)^n$, and show that this choice works uniformly for $|z|\le R$.

Answer (score 1):

Either go to the definition as suggested by Greg Martin, or apply [Weierstrass' M-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test): Let $\alpha = R/|z_0| < 1$. On $|z| \le R$, we have

$$
\left|\frac{z}{z_0} \right|^n \le \frac{R^n}{|z_0|^n} = \alpha^n$$
and the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha^n$ is a convergent geometric series.